# How can I control in-line decimal length so I can write stats with different length decimals in same sentence?

Tags: r, inline-code

I know that `options(digits = 4)` allows you to control the number of decimals in your output, but I often want to write stats in-line with different decimal counts (e.g., 2 decimal places for betas and 3 decimal places for p-values).  How can I control decimal length so I can  write stats with different length decimals in same line?

```
# create a new dataframe
d <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 0)); d
d$condition <- rbinom(n=10, size=1, prob=0.5); d 
d$lbs <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 150, sd = 25); d

# simple model to pull stats from for in-line writing
summary(m <- lm(lbs ~ condition, d))
```

Condition does not significantly predict weight, *β* = `coef(summary(m))["condition","Estimate"]`, *p* = `coef(summary(m))["condition","Pr(>|t|)"]`.

Comment: And your question certainly doesn't have anything to do with [tag:inline-code].

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can use the format function within your inline code to adjust the length of each reported stat. The inline code I include below is displaying as "e.g., Increased height predicts increased weight, β = 0.36, p = 0.852." when I knit a word document from this code.

```
# create a new dataframe
d <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 10, ncol = 0)); d

# add some variable values
d$lbs <- rnorm(n = 10, mean = 150, sd = 25)
d$inches <- rnorm(n = nrow(d), mean = 65, sd = 5)

# create a model to pull stats from
summary(m <- lm(lbs ~ inches, d))
```

e.g., Increased height predicts increased weight, *β* = `r  format(coef(summary(m))["inches","Estimate"], digits=2)`, *p* = `r  format(coef(summary(m))["inches","Pr(>|t|)"], digits=3)`.